# Please tell me how to get sweeper out my wallet

Tags: wallets

I Will pay anything to get this sweeper out my wallet anyone help!!my funds have been getting forwarded out my wallet for a Long time and I can't stop it

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

That wallet is gone. If someone knows your private key, they can submit as many transactions as they want and there's nothing you can do to stop them.

Create a new private key and Ethereum address.

Comment: Can't I put a sweeper on their sweeper or stop

Answer (score 0):

Using this tutorial
https://blog.mycrypto.com/how-to-beat-an-ethereum-based-sweeper-and-recover-your-assets/

I used the flashbots and i was able to remove my tokens from the compromised wallets by paying for the transaction fee from another wallet, i can help you too

Answer (score 0):

You can not stop sweeper bot. You need to create new wallet seed and transfer all funds to it. It can be a problem if bot sweeping all fee you send to compromised wallet. In this case you can try this service [unsweep.me](https://unsweep.me)